# No Output from Package Manager Console

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I create a new solution in VS Community 2019 and the console seems to load fine.

I issue the command: "get-help Nuget" and hit enter.

The cursor moves to the next line, but nothing happens.

It's not hanging, either, cause I can delete what I just typed.

It's not evaluating anything, no matter what I do;)

Any pointers as to what I can try?

Visual Studio 2019 is updated.

Comment: had this been working previously?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I did however just download VS 2022 Preview 2 and it works fine there.